# My salesforce training account has expired, now I can not login to trailhead Can I get my achieved badges in another account?

Tags: login, trailhead, superbadges

I started using salesforce with a Trial account, now the account has expired and I can not log in.

I had a lot of trailhead badges, in the account and now I can't access.

Is there any way to get the badges in another account?

I can't open a case since support is just for premium users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the directions in [this article](https://force.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/2896949-lost-access-to-the-salesforce-identity-used-to-log-into-trailhead). I'm not going to copy and paste the text verbatim, but basically you want to [create a new developer edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) (if you don't have one yet), [log a case](https://force.desk.com/customer/portal/emails/new) (note, this form does not require authentication), and they'll contact you back to get the problem fixed. They also recommend linking your Trailhead account to one of the available Social Login methods so you can use your social media account to log in to Trailhead.